# Is it better to JOIN on id or to save string value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `mvuser` wih attributes `user_id (int) (PRIMARY_KEY), username (varchar) (KEY), email (varchar)`,..., table `job` with attributes `job_id (int) (PRIMARY_KEY), job_name (varchar) (KEY)` and a table user_job.

Is it better for table `user_job` to have attributes `user_id (int), job_id (int)`, or to have attributes `username (varchar), job_name (varchar)` and why? Which one is faster?

Table `user_job` will be always queried with username or with job_name, for example:

```
SELECT job_name from user_job WHERE user_job.username='Username'
```

or

```
SELECT job_name FROM user_job JOIN mvuser ON mvuser.user_id = user_job.user_id
                              JOIN job ON job.job_name = user_job.job_name
                WHERE username='Username'
```

and similar when you query users by job_name.

I know that solution with `user_id (int), job_id (int)` is better if username and job_name can be changed, but in this case they can't, they are permanent.

Comment: It's faster to compare numbers rather than strings

Comment: depends which is your primary key.. which I suppose is the `Id` and not the names

Comment: You compare strings in both queries. In both queries you have WHERE username='Username'.

Comment: An important factor is whether username and job_name are 100% unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prefere joining on the `user_id` and `job_id` as this is your primary key and is indexed by default (always try to join on indexed columns) also integer comparison is faster than string comparison.

If your usernames are unique you could also optimize your `where` clause by using the `user_id` instead of the username (as the user_id is indexed and the username is not). Otherwise it could speed up your query if create an index on `username`.

But the general practice is:

If you don't have a performance problem, don't over optimize it and ceep it readable.

If you have a performance problem, you need to measure it before and after the optimization. If you can't measure an improvement a theoretical speedup will not help your for your real problem.

Comment: username is also indexed. Also in both queries you compare strings (WHERE username='Username'), because user will give username as a parameter, not user_id, and it can't be done in other way.